# JSON schema validdation - oneOf with array of mixed object type

Tags: json, jsonschema

I am trying to build up a JSON schema, where the JSON data has an array of mixed object types. I am trying to use `oneOf`, however, it seems that I am missing something, as my JSON data fails to validate against the schema.

Below are what I have done so far.

`Schema:`

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
        "Entity": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "Property": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Value": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [ "Property", "Value" ]
        },
        "NavEntity": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "Property": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "NavigationalEntities": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Entity"
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [ "Property", "NavigationalEntities" ]
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": true,
    "name": "/",
    "properties": {
        "Entities": {
            "type": "array",
            "minLength": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
                "oneOf": [
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/Entity" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/NavEntity" }
                ],
                "additionalProperties": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my JSON data:

```
{
    "Entities": [
        {
            "Property": "ABC",
            "NavigationalEntities": [
                {
                    "Property": "ABC1",
                    "Value": "123"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "Property": "ABCD",
            "Value": "ABCD"
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to validate this, I get error: `"Additional properties not allowed"`. This can also be seen [here](http://geraintluff.github.io/tv4/try/#?data=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22Entities%22%3A%20[%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Property%22%3A%20%22ABC%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22NavigationalEntities%22%3A%20[%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Property%22%3A%20%22ABC1%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Value%22%3A%20%22123%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20]%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Property%22%3A%20%22ABCD%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Value%22%3A%20%22ABCD%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20]%0A%7D&schema=%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%22%24schema%22%3A%20%22http%3A%2F%2Fjson-schema.org%2Fdraft-04%2Fschema%23%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22object%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22definitions%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Entity%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22object%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22additionalProperties%22%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Property%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Value%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22required%22%3A%20[%20%22Property%22%2C%20%22Value%22%20]%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22NavEntity%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22object%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22additionalProperties%22%3A%20false%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Property%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22string%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22NavigationalEntities%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22array%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22items%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22%24ref%22%3A%20%22%23%2Fdefinitions%2FEntity%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22required%22%3A%20[%20%22Property%22%2C%20%22NavigationalEntities%22%20]%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22additionalProperties%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22name%22%3A%20%22%2F%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%22properties%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22Entities%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22type%22%3A%20%22array%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22minLength%22%3A%201%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22uniqueItems%22%3A%20true%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22items%22%3A%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22oneOf%22%3A%20[%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22%24ref%22%3A%20%22%23%2Fdefinitions%2FEntity%22%20%7D%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7B%20%22%24ref%22%3A%20%22%23%2Fdefinitions%2FNavEntity%22%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20]%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%22additionalProperties%22%3A%20false%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D).

Please let me know what I am missing here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the `"additionalProperties": false` included in the `items` keyword within the `Entities` property.
You are specifying both:

- all items should not have any additional properties that those
  defined in `items` object (and you did not define any).
- all items must verify one of `Entity` or `NavEntity`.

If you remove the last `"additionalProperties": false`, everything is ok. And you don't need it because both `Entity` and `NavEntity` have it included.

Proposed schema:

```
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "definitions": {
        "Entity": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "Property": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "Value": {
                    "type": "string"
                }
            },
            "required": [ "Property", "Value" ]
        },
        "NavEntity": {
            "type": "object",
            "additionalProperties": false,
            "properties": {
                "Property": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "NavigationalEntities": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                        "$ref": "#/definitions/Entity"
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [ "Property", "NavigationalEntities" ]
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": true,
    "name": "/",
    "properties": {
        "Entities": {
            "type": "array",
            "minLength": 1,
            "uniqueItems": true,
            "items": {
                "oneOf": [
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/Entity" },
                    { "$ref": "#/definitions/NavEntity" }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I see. I thought if I don't specify `"additionalProperties": true,`, I will leave a 'gap' of allowing invalid objects. However, 'invalidation' of any invalid object is covered by `oneOf` array, and I don't need to do anything more. Is that right?